# Readjust data from matrix to to transnational format

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame that has the following form (my data spans 12 months):

```
df <- data.frame(January = c(10,11,12,99,100,101), February = c(13,14,15,23,34,56), March = c(16,17,18,76,87,33),April = c(130,141,152,969,1010,1201), May = c(113,114,115,213,314,561), June = c(162,172,182,762,872,332))  
rownames(df) <- c("Males","Females","0-24","25-44","45-64","65+")
```

This is how the data looks like:

```
        January February March April May June  
Males        10       13    16   130 113  162  
Females      11       14    17   141 114  172  
0-24         12       15    18   152 115  182  
25-44        99       23    76   969 213  762  
45-64       100       34    87  1010 314  872  
65+         101       56    33  1201 561  332
```

I would like to reorganize it so that better analyse it and chart it. An ideal format would be as follows:

```
Month, Sex (rows 1 and 2 of each column), AgeGroup (rows 3 - 6 of each column).
```

How can I go about this please?

Following a comment the numbers given here are made up. The actual data is sourced from http://www.opendatamalta.org/ckan/dataset/50cfd96f-246e-4d57-a0ce-86c8ce88e9d6/resource/fad12a26-2965-404f-9320-c0bc82353315/download/Profileofdepartingtourists2012.csv.

IMO, the ideal format would be two data frames:

*dfSex*

```
Month    -   Sex.Factor  -  Sex.Value
January  -   M           -  10
January  -   F           -  11
February -   M           -  13 
February -   F           -  14
March    -   M           -  16 
March    -   F           -  17
**etc**
```

*dfAgeG*

```
Month     -  AgeG.Factor  - AgeG.Value
January  -   0-24         -  12
January  -   25-44        -  99
January  -   45-64        -  100 
January  -   65+          -  101
February -   0-24         -  15
February -   25-44        -  23
February -   45-64        -  34 
February -   65+          -  101
March    -   0-24         -  18
March    -   25-44        -  76
March    -   45-64        -  87 
March    -   65+          -  33
**etc**
```

Comment: @ananda-mahto: I already cleaned the data removing columns I do not need.

Comment: @ananda-mahto: I realize that the data needs to be split into two separate data sets for me to achieve what I want. Sex must go into one data set and age group must go into another. I have done this with the reshape2 package.

After that I need to visit each data set and figure out how I can create a factor variable and value (by month). For sex, this would be Month - Sex.Factor - Sex.Value and for the age group data set this would be Month - AgeG.Factor - AgeG.Value

Comment: @ananda-mahto: Thanks. Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments under the answer, `melt` from "reshape2" should be sufficient (and pretty direct) for this problem. It actually also works very nicely with `t(df)` since it calls the `matrix` method for `melt`, which makes use of `rownames` in creating variables in the resulting `data.frame`.

Here's the approach:

```
library(reshape2)
## You can refer to the columns by name
melt(t(df)[, c("Males", "Females")])
#        Var1    Var2 value
# 1   January   Males    10
# 2  February   Males    13
# 3     March   Males    16
# 4     April   Males   130
# 5       May   Males   113
# 6      June   Males   162
# 7   January Females    11
# 8  February Females    14
# 9     March Females    17
# 10    April Females   141
# 11      May Females   114
# 12     June Females   172

## Or by column number. Notice that I use `nrow`
##   from the original un-transposed dataset as
##   a point of reference for convenience.
## Here are just the first 10 rows.
head(melt(t(df)[, 3:nrow(df)]), 10)
#        Var1  Var2 value
# 1   January  0-24    12
# 2  February  0-24    15
# 3     March  0-24    18
# 4     April  0-24   152
# 5       May  0-24   115
# 6      June  0-24   182
# 7   January 25-44    99
# 8  February 25-44    23
# 9     March 25-44    76
# 10    April 25-44   969
```